# How to handle hardcoded stuffs in database and coding

Tags: php, mysql

There are some language and courses(based on language) are defined in two table. Language table reference is used in course table to relate course with particular language. I also have a notes table that content notes of specific course and that is related to course table. Now I have two issues.

1. Now in coding I need to take some specific action for Spanish language only. So how should I handle this as languages will be entered by users and we would not be having any idea about Spanish language ID. If I do use text (the language name) then each time I need to fetch ID for Spanish from language table and then will fetch all course related to this from course table.
2. Suppose Spanish notes are stored in four separate sections and other notes have only one section so should I use same table with four column (one for each section) or use two tables(notes and spanish_notes). Using former way, will leave three column blank for other languages notes. I don't think that is good.

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution to your first issue about multiple languages is to use language codes such as 'en', 'es', 'fr' etc. For instance in your `language` table you could have both `id, code` columns but in your content tables you could have a FK with code. So you could either get this lang. code from requests `Accept-Language` property. or somewhere else.

For second question in terms of normalization it is better to have separate tables for Spanish notes. It is way better for many reasons such as redundancy and dependency concerns.

EDIT: PS. You could also have a look at language codes from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) and HTTP Accept-Language from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accept-Language#Accept-Language).

Comment: Do you want that user also select a code when enter the language or I do mapping with language code in php coding having all language name and their code hardcoded and  for second issue i agree with lucy.

Comment: @Lucy as far as I understand from example phpian is trying to have Spanish specific notes within the global notes table i.e. think that column1 is valid for all languages and column2 is valid for only spanish. So you will have a table with most of fields null and will never be used for other languages. This breaks redundancy rule of normalization.

Comment: @phpian it depends on php implementation details which I am not aware of. But usinng standard language codes give you the opportunity to get default language from browser or user. That is what I am trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Some inputs:

1. There could be 2 ways of doing this:

   a. When languages are entered by users, use a `SELECT` dropdown box for accepting user inputs. For each SELECT option, you can set the language name as the text and language id as the value. This way you will know the language ID as

   b. You can use MySQL `INNER JOIN` between "language" and "courses" table, something like:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM `language` `l`
   INNER JOIN `courses` `c` ON `l`.`language_id` = `c`.`language_id`
   WHERE `l`.`language_name` = `spanish`;
   ```
2. I think it's okay to keep all notes for all sections in the single table. So, for the other 3 columns that will only contain Spanish notes, you can set them to accept NULL values

Hope it helps.